# Native Windows Phone 8 Image API

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8, crop

I amd trying to implement a Windows Phone 8 application that changes the lockscreen image. A part of the code that writes the image to Isolated Storage is as follows:

```
private async void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
        {
            if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    store.Remove();
                }
                BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
                bi.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
                WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bi);
                byte[] buffer = null;
                using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
                {
                    int quality = 80;
                    e.ChosenPhoto.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                    // TODO: Crop or rotate here if needed

                    wb.SaveJpeg(ms, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, quality);
                    buffer = ms.ToArray();
                }
                var isoFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
                var nextImageName = Guid.NewGuid() + ".jpg";
                var newImageFile = await isoFolder.CreateFileAsync(nextImageName, Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.FailIfExists);
                using (var wfs = await newImageFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
                {
                    wfs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }
                Windows.Phone.System.UserProfile.LockScreen.SetImageUri(new Uri("ms-appdata:///Local/" + nextImageName, UriKind.Absolute));
                MessageBox.Show("You have successfully set a new background");
            }
        }
```

In the middle of the code you see the following comment:

```
// TODO: Crop or rotate here if needed
```

My question is:

What is the code for the native image cropping? (e.g. like the one that you see when you choose a photo for your lockscreen through native Windows Phone lockscreen settings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `PhotoChooserTask`, you can set the desired values to the `PixelHeight` and `PixelWidth` properties and it will automatically show the native image cropping page:

```
photoChooser.PixelHeight = 500;
photoChooser.PixelWidth = 500;
```

However there is no way to open it from elsewhere (i.e without a `PhotoChooseTask`).

Comment: Thanks Mr. Payen) Works like a charm! Is there a way to bind photoChooser.PixelHeight and Widht to the proportions of the device the application is running on?

Comment: Here's the answer to my last question:

`if(App.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor == 100)
{
  // WVGA
}
else if (App.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor == 160)
{
  // WXGA
}
else if (App.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor == 150)
{
  // 720p
}`

Comment: "The recommended lock screen image size for lock screen is 480px X 800px or 960px X 1708px. If larger image is provided it will be cropped from centre and set in lock screen: if a smaller image is provided then it will be stretched to fit the screen (and may be blurred/scratched)." (http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Dynamic_Lock_Screen_for_Windows_Phone_8)